# Automating data from an Excel file and interacting with browser

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, automation, automator

How can I automate copying records from an Excel file or CSV and interacting with a browser?

**Example Task:**

1. Extract or Copy record(s) from an Excel file row
2. Go to a URL (probably using Google Chrome)
3. Put that data that was copied from the Excel file to the form of the page
4. Run some scripts or press some bookmarklets I prepared inside the browser (Google Chrome)
5. Save or Done!
6. Go to next record/row of the Excel or CSV file.

I like the built-in Automator of Mac but I am not sure if it's capable of what I am asking to do. One complicated task that I see is looping the records from the Excel file or CSV.

For example, after a task is done, going to the next record and repeat the task.

Comment: That looks like a Rube Goldberg solution — what kind of scripts would that be? If those aren't too complicated you can probably submit a form through command line, which would be much easier.

Comment: I prepared some bookmarklet done in javascript also interacting with the DOM elements. eg, override dates or submit form etc. If it can interact with the browser, like it can click my bookmarklet, then it's good.

Comment: my main functionality I am looking for is, go thru my excel file. get the records, go to a url, interact with the form (fill form and submit etc), and interact with my browser, click some bookmarklets.

Comment: Certainly doable, but probably hell of a job since you will be automating a lot. I'll see if I have the time to check it out, but at that point, just for making things easier, trying (or buying) [UIBrowser](http://pfiddlesoft.com/uibrowser/index.html) would be an idea worth considering I guess ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) plugin for Firefox (if you can't find the right version, go to their website), it's very advanced (you can record and do some customization later), but it doesn't work outside of the web browser, so I'd have to import your Excel document into [Google Docs](https://drive.google.com/).
The other alternatives are [BadBoy](http://www.badboy.com.au/) or [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) (more advanced, you can paste the rows from CSV format and parse it from there), iMacros, [Watij](http://watij.com/), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a programable keyboard like the Razer Nostromo?

I have one & it comes with a scripting functionality that starts up at the hit of a button. I have used it for loading files over and over again when I have 100's of them that need to be loaded one at a time.

Here's a link to what I'm talking about.
[http://www.amazon.com/Razer-Nostromo-Gaming-Keypad-RZ07-00490100-R3/dp/B004AM5RB6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004AM5RB6)

Comment: No, I haven't... but it looks cool. But I'll try first my luck on software side. thanks!